# Short hand for "../../node_modules/.bin/"?

Tags: node-modules, lerna

In a lerna monorepo, I want to:

- Not have typescript as a dev dependency on each package. Rather, I'd have it installed as dev dependency in the project root.
- Have a `build` script in each package.

Now - according to [this issue](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/470) CLI packages (ie. those that live in the `node_modules/.bin` folder) aren't available for module resolution the way regular packages are.

That is, I can't have a script that looks like this:

```
"build": "tsc -v"
```

Because the `tsc` binary isn't actually available to it.

To get around this, I can do a relative file reference like:

```
"build" : "../../node_modules/.bin/tsc -v"
```

This works fine, but it's a little bit clumsy.

What I was hoping is that I could have a command similar to `$(npm bin)` or `$(yarn bin)`, but one that refers the `.bin` folder of the project root, not the current package.

Answer (score 2):

I think the basic issue here is that you need `../../node_modules/.bin/` in your `$PATH` variable, but the exact directory needs to be dynamically computed.

In python land, you could execute a .pythonstartup script upon `source ./venv/bin/activate`. Javascript, however, doesn't require an explicit activate step.

If we are dealing with pure CLI, then you could create a bash function to dynamically do the lookup:

```
function set-project-path() {
  BASH_PATH=${BASH_PATH:-$PATH}  # only set variable if unset
  for DIR in . .. ../.. ../../.. ../../../.. ; do  # set to required lookup depth
    DIR=$DIR/node_modules/.bin
    if [[ -d $DIR ]]; then 
        PATH=`pwd $DIR`:$BASH_PATH;
        echo "set-project-path(): \$PATH += `pwd $DIR`";
        break; 
    fi;
  done;
}
function unset-project-path() {
  PATH="${BASH_PATH:-$PATH}"  # reset to $BASH_PATH if previously set 
}
```

This would require manual activation by manually running:

```
set-project-path
```

Using `pwd` gives you an absolute path, which means you can move between directories inside your project. However, the script will need to be rerun each time you change to a different project.

In theory, this script could be run in `.bashrc`, but this assumes that bash is starting somewhere inside the project directory tree.

If you wanted to get really fancy, you could try injecting this script into the `$PS1` variable that gets called before every render of the command prompt.

Another approach would be to simply symlink `tsc` or `node_modules` into each package subdirectory, which is another way of making a script visible within your `$PATH`, but without causing synchronization or filespace issues.